# How to use user made png/jpeg icons in QGIS 2.0?

Tags: qgis-2, svg, jpg, png, icon

I can only add svg icons in qgis 2.0. How can i use png or jpeg or gif images as icons in qgis2.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

link to site on how to do embed a jpeg or png in a svg file
http://snorf.net/blog/2014/02/27/embedding-pngs-in-svg-markers-in-qgis/

Answer (score 8):

This is currently not supported.  The only way you are able to do this is to embed or link a png in a SVG file.

Adding support for loading other image formats shouldn't be too hard for a future version.